The first integral cohomology of a smooth manifold is torsion free?
Suppose we have a good cover $U_{\alpha}$ of M. Then the Cech cohomology with respect to this cover is isomorphic to the singular cohomology. So just consider the problem by Cech cohomology.
We have a homomorphism $i:H^{1}(U_{\alpha},\mathbb{Z})\to H^{1}(U_{\alpha},\mathbb{Q})$ for the constant $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ sheaves. For a cocycle $u_{\alpha\beta}\in H^{1}(M,\mathbb{Z})$, if $i(u_{\alpha\beta})=0$, this means that $u_{\alpha\beta}=\delta f$ for some $f_{\alpha}\in C^0(U_{\alpha},\mathbb{Q})$. Then if we choose an open set $U_{\alpha_{0}}$, and define $g_{\alpha}=f_{\alpha}-f_{\alpha_{0}}$, it is easy to see that $g\in C^{0}(U_{\alpha},\mathbb{Z})$ because of good cover and $\delta g=u$. Thus $i$ is injective and consequently $H^{1}(U_{\alpha},\mathbb{Z})$ must be torsion free.
Here is some details for the easy to see part. Since we are working with good covers, $g_{\alpha}$'s are constant on $U_{\alpha}$'s because $f_{\alpha}$'s are. For any $U_{\alpha}$ intersects $U_{\alpha_{0}}$, we have $g_{\alpha}=g_{\alpha_{0}}-u_{\alpha\alpha_{0}}$ hence it is an integer. Then by connectedness of $M$, all $g_{\alpha}$'s are integers.

(This answer addresses an earlier version of the question which was about $H^2$.) As usual the problem comes from the step labeled "it is easy to see that" - I see no reason that $g$ should be an integral cocycle. What did you do to the denominators? You also make no use of the $2$, so if this argument worked it would prove that all the integral cohomology is torsion-free.
Here is an explicit counterexample. All homology and cohomology below is over $\mathbb{Z}$. First, let $X$ be any topological space. By the universal coefficient theorem we have a short exact sequence
$$0 \to \text{Ext}^1(H_1(X), \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X) \to \text{Hom}(H_2(X), \mathbb{Z}) \to 0$$
which splits (not naturally). If $H_1(X)$ is finitely generated with finite torsion subgroup $T$, and $H_2(X)$ is finitely generated with rank $s$, we have that $\text{Hom}(H_2(X), \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^s$ and that $\text{Ext}^1(H_1(X), \mathbb{Z}) \cong T$ (not naturally), from which it follows that
$$H^2(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}^s \oplus T.$$
So (with the mild finite generation hypotheses above, which are satisfied by e.g. any compact manifold) the torsion in $H^2$ is the same as the torsion in $H_1$. This means to get a counterexample it suffices to exhibit a compact smooth manifold with torsion in $H_1$. The simplest example is the real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$, which satisfies $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) \cong H_1(\mathbb{RP}^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$. We can even produce orientable examples such as the lens spaces.
In a positive direction, the universal coefficient theorem can be used to show that $H^1$ is torsion-free, since the first term $\text{Ext}^1(H_0(X), \mathbb{Z})$ vanishes, giving $H^1(X) \cong \text{Hom}(H_1(X), \mathbb{Z})$.

Thanks very much!!! My reasoning shows that $H^{1}$ is torsion free, it is true.

@Jiang: I still don't understand your argument. Where do you use the fact that you are working with $H^1$ specifically?

I mind was not clear just now. I thought that $u_{\alpha\beta}$ is an element of $H^{2}$ which is a stupid mistake. As for the easy to see part, first we have $g_{\alpha_{0}}=0$, and for any other $\alpha$'s, $g_{\alpha}$ can be connected to $g_{\alpha_{0}}=0$ by finite open covers, hence their difference must be an interger.

@Jiang: unfortunately I still do not understand what you mean. Maybe this argument can be made to work for $H^1$ but right now I still don't see how you're getting rid of denominators. Can you edit in more details?

@Yuan: I have provided details. And what do you mean by denominators? can you be specific?

@Jiang: okay, I think I understand the argument now (I am less familiar with Cech cohomology). I think this works provided you assume connectedness, and in general you can run the same argument on each connected component.
